# Fitting Differential Equations: curve_fit converges to local minima

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to fit the differential equation ay' + by''=0 to a curve by varying a and b The following code does not work. The problem with curve_fit seems to be that lack of initial guess results in failure in fitting. I also tried leastsq. Can anyone suggest me other ways to fit such differential equation? If I don't have good guess curve_fit fails!

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import linspace, random, array

time = linspace(0.0,10.0,100)
def deriv(time,a,b): 
    dy=lambda y,t : array([ y[1], a*y[0]+b*y[1] ])
    yinit = array([0.0005,0.2]) # initial values
    Y=odeint(dy,yinit,time)
    return Y[:,0]

z = deriv(time, 2, 0.1)
zn = z + 0.1*random.normal(size=len(time))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(deriv, time, zn)
print popt  # it only outputs the initial values of a, b!
```

Comment: Please, accept answers in the previous questions by you (green tick to the left of the answer) before we start going into answering this one.

Comment: @ovgolovin thank you for your suggestions. What I have is a set of numbers in course of time. I am trying to find out if the solution of this differential equation can be used fit the data.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use the closed form solution of the differential equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? The above code correctly prints `[ 1.99997875  0.10001344]` which indeed are the parameters in the data `zn` that was fitted?

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite the equation:

```
ay' + by''=0
y'' = -a/b*y'
```

So this equation may be represented in this way

```
dy/dt = y'
d(y')/dt = -a/b*y'
```

The code in Python 2.7:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import *

a = -2
b = -0.1

def deriv(Y,t):
    '''Get the derivatives of Y at the time moment t
Y = [y, y' ]'''
    return array([ Y[1], -a/b*Y[1] ])

time = linspace(0.0,1.0,1000)
yinit = array([0.0005,0.2]) # initial values
y = odeint(deriv,yinit,time)
figure()
plot(time,y[:,0])
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

You may compare the resultant plots with the plots in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%3D+-2%2F0.1%2ay%27%2C+y%280%29%3D0.0005%2C+y%27%280%29%3D0.2)

Comment: @pappu Could you add this comment to the question? Because it wasn't clear from the question. What I got was "What I can do is to solve the equation with odeint and make its plot.?".

Comment: @pappu Also, how the curve you are trying to fit to is set? Provide this information in the question either.

Comment: @pappu What you are asking is a curve fitting. Such tasks are solved with Machine Learning methods and they are not trivial. For example what is the criteria of closeness to the target curve? With the change of the criteria the resultant curve will be changing as well

Comment: @pappu The first idea is to implement `h` function which calculates the closeness between 2 curves. By varying `a` and `b` you would be getting different curves by solving the differential equation and so that different  values returned by the `h` function. Then using different optimization algorithms (e.g. gradient descent, etc.) you can find `a` and `b` which minimizes the `h` output. Those `a` and `b` would give the closest curve to the target curve in terms of the function `h` that you formulated.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the default initial guesses, read the documentation [curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to find out how to specify them manually by giving it the `p0` parameter. For instance, `curve_fit(deriv, time, zn, p0=(12, 0.23))` if you want `a=12` and `b=0.23` be the initial guess.

Comment: I checked it already. If I don't have good guess curve_fit fails!